# Running a Job on Spark 0.9.0 throws error

Tags: java, scala, hdfs, apache-spark

I have a Apache Spark 0.9.0 Cluster installed where I am trying to deploy a code which reads a file from HDFS. This piece of code throws a warning and eventually the job fails. Here is the code

```
/**
 * running the code would fail 
 * with a warning 
 * Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that 
 * workers are registered and have sufficient memory
 */

object Main extends App {
    val sconf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("spark://labscs1:7077")
    .setAppName("spark scala")
    val sctx = new SparkContext(sconf)
    sctx.parallelize(1 to 100).count
}
```

The below is the WARNING message

> Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to
>   ensure that  workers are registered and have sufficient memory

how to get rid of this or am I missing some configurations.

Comment: did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: As samthebest pointed out check your memory and cores. I saw same error today and realized my worker had only 64m allocated and the default spark.executor.memory is 512m. It keeps waiting for a worker with available memory. Changing worker memory settings made it work.

Comment: @SKP I'm running into the same issue, how did you change the worker memory settings?

Comment: e.g. for 3GB ```conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "3000m")```

Answer (score 5):

You get this when either the number of cores or amount of RAM (per node) you request via setting `spark.cores.max` and `spark.executor.memory` resp' exceeds what is available.  Therefore even if no one else is using the cluster, and you specify you want to use, say 100GB RAM per node, but your nodes can only support 90GB, then you will get this error message.

To be fair the message is vague in this situation, it would be more helpful if it said your exceeding the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Spark master can't assign any workers for this task. Either the workers aren't started or they are all busy.

Check Spark UI on master node (port specified by `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT` in `spark-env.sh`, 8080 by default). It should look like this: [image: SparkUI Sample]

For cluster to function properly:

- There must be some workers with state "Alive"
- There must be some cores available (for example, if all cores are busy with the frozen task, the cluster won't accept new tasks)
- There must be sufficient memory available

Comment: I chekced with the webUI it has the wokers alive but with only 1 GB memory on each

Comment: @prassee: That should be enough. Is this memory listed as free or used? It may help to click individual workers and check the logs.

Comment: Try to run `MASTER=spark://labscs1:7077 spark-shell` on the same machine you're trying to run the code. And the same code in spark console: `sc.parallelize(1 to 100).count`. Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure your spark workers can communicate both ways with the driver. Check for firewalls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue. I had a simple 1-node Spark cluster and was getting this error when trying to run my Spark app.

I ran through some of the suggestions above and it was when I tried to run the Spark shell against the cluster and not being able to see this in the UI that I became suspicious that my cluster was not working correctly.

In my hosts file I had an entry, let's say `SparkNode`, that referenced the correct IP Address.

I had inadvertently put the wrong IP Address in the `conf/spark-env.sh` file against the `SPARK_MASTER_IP` variable. I changed this to `SparkNode` and I also changed `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to point to `SparkNode`.

To test this I opened up the UI using `SparkNode:7077` in the browser and I could see an instance of Spark running.

I then used Wildfires suggestion of running the Spark shell, as follows:

```
MASTER=spark://SparkNode:7077 bin/spark-shell
```

Going back to the UI I could now see the Spark shell application running, which I couldn't before.

So I exited the Spark shell and ran my app using Spark Submit and it now works correctly.

It is definitely worth checking out all of your IP and host entries, this was the root cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the right SPARK_HOME and your driver program's IP address in case Spark may not able to locate your Netty jar server. Be aware that your Spark master should listen to the correct IP address which you suppose to use. This can be done by setting SPARK_MASTER_IP=yourIP in file spark-env.sh.

```
   val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("test")
  .setMaster("spark://yourSparkMaster:7077")
  .setSparkHome("YourSparkHomeDir")
  .set("spark.driver.host", "YourIPAddr")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors regard to hostname, IP address and loopback. Make sure to set `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` and `SPARK_MASTER_IP`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue Initial job has not accepted any resource, fixed it by specify the spark correct download url on spark-env.sh or installing spark on all slaves.

```
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/spark/spark-1.6.1/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
```

*Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory*