# how to run python script in spark job?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have setup spark on 3 machines using tar file method. I have not done any advanced configuration, I have edited slaves file and started master and workers. I am able to see sparkUI on 8080 port. Now I want to run simple python script on spark cluster.

```
import sys
from random import random
from operator import add

from pyspark import SparkContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
        Usage: pi [partitions]
    """
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonPi")
    partitions = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 2
    n = 100000 * partitions

    def f(_):
        x = random() * 2 - 1
        y = random() * 2 - 1
        return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1 else 0

    count = sc.parallelize(xrange(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
    print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / n)

    sc.stop()
```

I am running this command

> spark-submit --master spark://IP:7077 pi.py 1

But getting following error

```
14/12/22 18:31:23 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
14/12/22 18:31:38 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
14/12/22 18:31:43 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://10.77.36.243:7077...
14/12/22 18:31:53 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
14/12/22 18:32:03 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://10.77.36.243:7077...
14/12/22 18:32:08 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
14/12/22 18:32:23 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
14/12/22 18:32:23 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
14/12/22 18:32:23 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
14/12/22 18:32:23 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Failed to run reduce at /opt/pi.py:21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pi.py", line 21, in <module>
    count = sc.parallelize(xrange(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 759, in reduce
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 723, in collect
    bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.collect.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
```

does anyone facing same issue. Plz help in this.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

suggests that the cluster does not have any available resources.

Check the status of your cluster and inspect cores and RAM (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/common-spark-troubleshooting).

Also, double check your IP addresses.

For more ideas: [Running a Job on Spark 0.9.0 throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677142/running-a-job-on-spark-0-9-0-throws-error)